# How to insert data into postgis database with phpPgAdmin?

Tags: postgis

I have 50 line objects in .shp format in folder on my computer. I need to insert it to postgis database on the distant server.. When I log in in phpPgAdmin, it says it runs on localhost:5433. What is the quick way to insert my .shp data into database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run shp2pgsql to convert the shapefile into SQL. You should be able to execute the resulting SQL file in phpPgAdmin.

QGIS offers a GUI for shp2pgsql via "Postgis Manager" plugin. You can connect to the remote database and load shapefiles directly without the need for phpPgAdmin.

Comment: I don't understand where to find Postgis Manager plugin?

Comment: I found it, I'll try it now.

Comment: I can't connect to my database.

Comment: Note: Postgres has to be configured to listen to external IPs. This is not enabled by default

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to use SSH tunnels - use putty (or other SSH client) to log in to the remote machine and set a tunnel from localhost:5433 to remotemachine:5433. See http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/ for more details. Then you can run PGAdmin on your local machine and it will talk directly to the remote machine.

Comment: I can't connect to database. I tried with putty but it doesn't work.

Comment: if you log into the remote machine can you access the DB?

Answer (score 3):

On windows **PgAdmin III is under Start->Programs->PostgreSQL 8.4->PgAdmin III**
Login with the super user usually postgres and the password you chose during install. If you forgot it, then go into **pg_hba.conf** (just open it with an editor such as notepad or a programmer editor). Set the line

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/5433 md5

to

host all all 127.0.0.1/5433 trust
```

if you trust it use

```
host all all localhost/5433 trust (host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 will give all users access)
```